# @Exclude decorator not working on POST methods, but works in GET methods

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, class-transformer

I'm doing a nestjs application, with typeorm in postgress

I'm trying to exclude the `password` and `accessToken` columns in my JSON return, but it does not work when creating a new user. I tried using `@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)` but it did not worked.

Here's the snippet of my code.

**user.entity.ts**

```js
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsEmail } from 'class-validator';
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';
import { UserRoles } from './user.interface';

@Entity()
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  userId: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  role: UserRoles;

  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isActive: boolean;

  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  @Column()
  accessToken: string;
```

**user.controller.ts**

```js
  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  async signup(@Body(new ValidationPipe({transform: true})) user: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    if (user.password == user.verifyPassword) {
      const newuser = await this.userService.createUser(user);

      if (newuser.userId) {
        await this.mailService.sendVerificationEmail(newuser);
      }
      return newuser;
    } else {
      throw new HttpException(
        MESSAGES.PASSWORD_NOTMATCH_ERROR,
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }
  }
```

**user.service.ts**

```js
  async createUser(user: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 12);
    user.accessToken = crypto.randomBytes(40).toString('hex');
    user.accessTokenExpiry = new Date(
      new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1),
    );

    return this.userRepository.save(user);
  }
```

**main.ts**

```js
import { ClassSerializerInterceptor, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)));
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
}
bootstrap();
```

Let me know if I missed something or there is something that I did incorrectly

Comment: Are you returning an instance of `UserEntity`?

Comment: I have tried return an instance of `UserEntity` and it still did not work